# C++ {fmt} format dynamically repeat argument

Tags: c++, fmt

I need to match a file format that heavily relies on tab-based indentation.
Is there an idiomatic way to repeatedly insert a character (in my case `\t`) a given `n` number of times using {fmt}?

I'm looking for something similar to how the alignment works:

```cpp
fmt::format("{:>{}}", "right aligned", 30);
// Result: "                 right aligned"
```

All the solutions I came up with feel contrived.

Comment: specify fill character? `"{:\t>{}}"` ? Please post example output that you want to have. Ex. for `"right aligned", 30` you want to output 15 (or something like that) tab characters followed by the string "right aligned"?

Comment: No, it's far simpler. I basically want to set the indentation level (how many tabs) that go before the beginning of the line, and I would like to avoid writing `fmt::format("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHello world")`.

Comment: `fmt::format("{:\t>{}}", "", 15)` ?

Comment: Makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [fmt::format string syntax](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#grammar-token-fill) allows to specify a fill character. You can print an empty string and specify the fill character to tabs and then "regulate" how many tabulations are printed.

```
int count = 10;
fmt::format("{:\t>{}}", "", count);
```

Comment: Note that the 'fill' character must be a single character, not a string. And that field does not accept a dynamic replacement field. So, if you want to use "XY" as the padding prefix, this doesn't work. But something like "two spaces" can be accomplished by using a single space character and doubling the count parameter.